# Sync two different s3 buckets on different accounts on an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

my goal is I would like to be able to run aws cli with this command `aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://destination-bucket` on an ec2 instance. The source and destination buckets reside in different accounts and I do not own the source account. I have seen plenty of examples of how to sync s3 buckets that reside in different accounts not using an ec2 instance. Although those examples don't translate as well when I am working with ec2 instance and granting permissions with this middle man (the e2c instance).

I have read it is best to use an IAM Roles to give permission when working with the ec2 instance. Here is what I have currently configured:

This is the policy that has been attached to my IAM Role which also is assigned to ec2 instance on my destination account. From my understanding it gives my ec2 instance permission to my destination s3 bucket for listing, downloading ect.. Also the policy allows you me to assume the **s3-role** on the source account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<source account number>:role/s3-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

On the source account I have created just the **s3-role** and configured it to have the account number of the destination account as a trusted entity. Here is what the policy attached to the s3-role looks like:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally on my ec2 instance I configured my aws cli with a profile so I could assume the role on the source account. Here is what it looks like:

```
[profile foundation]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<source account number>:role/s3-role

credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

Then when I run the command `aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://destination-bucket --profile foundation`.  I get this error, (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied. I  suspect the issue is I am using the named profile that might be just giving access to the source account, but I really don't know.

I just am not sure how to grant permission so that the ec2 instance can access the source account without assuming the role. I am not sure if I also need to attach a policy to the s3 buckets too if so, I am not sure what I would put in them. One last important piece of info is I can access both bucket individually just fine with commands like cp and ls.

Some direction on this would be really appreciated sorry if the answer is obvious I am new to aws, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that assuming a role on the source bucket is not necessary for giving permissions to allow the sync to happen. On the attached policy of the s3 source bucket   I added this to the statement section

```
{
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<destination account number>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket"
            ]
        }
```

then on my IAM Role attached to the ec2 instance on my destination account I added this to the statements section

```
 {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
```

I was then able to run this command just fine `aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://destination-bucket`